# Need to set a cookie client-side and immediately use it server-side

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

For a variety of reasons I need my server-side PHP code to be aware of the client's window width. I've tried the following PHP snippet:

```
echo '
  <html>
    <head>
      <title>Yadda yadda</title>
      <!-- Etc... -->
      <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-1.10.1.min.js">
      </script>
     <script>
      document.cookie="resH="+$(window).width()+"; path=/";
     </script>
  </head>
  <body>
';

if (isset ($_COOKIE ['resH'])) {
    // do stuff
  } else
    // do other stuff
}
```

The problem is that when I check for the cookie, the browser has not yet had the time to set it and notify the server of this fact. In other words, this is sufficiently asynchronous to mess up my timing, and the cookie check either fails or uses the cookies set on the *previous* page load.

Is there a way to address this, or is my only option to abandon this approach in favor of something completely different?

Comment: You haven't shown how the client sends the width to the server - oh and this isn't asynchronous, this is server serving a web page to a client

Comment: why dont u use variable to store width of window instead of cookie

Comment: your problem is that client side code will always run after server side code,  the only way to achieve what you want is to do an ajax call to load your page, that way you'd be able to pass the width into the load (I would recommend against this though unless you provide a non js backup).  What do you need the width for anyway?  Surely any changes to layout should be done via css and not coded into the server side stuff?

Comment: You could just use an AJAX request to the PHP on the server, which would store data directly in `$_SESSION` (for example).